# Object has no method hammer (Hammer, Backbone, RequireJS)

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, hammer.js

I'm trying to integrate Hammer JS in my Backbone application, but I'm getting the error: **Object [object Object] has no method 'hammer'**.
I'm using Backbone with RequireJS.
The error occurs when I call the method **hammer()** on my **this.$el**.

Here's the code that I'm using.

**app.js**

```
require.config({

    baseUrl: 'js/libs',

    paths: {
        // Directories
        collections: '../collections',
        models: '../models',
        views: '../views',
        templates: '../../templates',

        // Files
        dualStorage: 'backbone.dualStorage',
        hammer: 'hammer.min',
        jQueryHammer: 'jquery.hammer.min',
        jQueryAnimate: 'jquery.animate-enhanced.min'
    },

    shim: {
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'jQueryHammer': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'hammer']
        },
        'dualStorage': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'backbone']
        }
    }
});

require([
    'jquery',
    'backbone',
    'hammer',
    'jQueryHammer',
    '../router'
], function($, Backbone, Hammer, jQueryHammer, Router) {
    var router = new Router();
});
```

**view.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'text!templates/avatar/StyleAvatarTemplate.html',
    'hisrc',
    'hammer',
    'jQueryHammer',
    'jQueryAnimate'
], function($, _, Backbone, styleAvatarTemplate) {

    var StyleAvatarView = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function(options) {
            this.gender = options.gender;
            this.age = options.age;
        },

        events: {
            "swipe": "changeStyle"
        },

        changeStyle: function(e) {
            alert('test');
            console.log(e);
        },

        render: function() {
            var data = {
                collection: this.collection.models,
                gender: this.gender,
                age: this.age,
                _: _
            };

            this.template = _.template(styleAvatarTemplate, data);

            this.$el.html(this.template);
            this.$el.hammer();

            return this;
        }

    });

    return StyleAvatarView;
});
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please check it with `console.log($.fn.hammer);` before call it.

Comment: I just tried and I get "undefined"

Comment: Bad, please check this https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/issues/331 it has 2 jsfiddle with working plugin.

Comment: Thnx Eugene! I used the config from the jsfiddle and that solved my problem.

Comment: great! Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible jQuery plugins for Hammer:

- [One](https://github.com/EightMedia/jquery.hammer.js/blob/master/jquery.hammer.js) which includes Hammer in it.
- [Another](https://github.com/EightMedia/jquery.hammer.js/blob/master/jquery.hammer-standalone.js) which does *not* include Hammer in it.

I suggest you use the second one.

Why? First, because the setup you show in your question has Hammer in its own file (`hammer.min`) so there's no point in using a plugin that *also* includes Hammer in it. But second, and more importantly, looking at the code in the version of the plugin that includes Hammer in it, I see it using calls to `define` in a way that is fragile. Basically, if it works, that's just luck. (And there are bug reports that support my evaluation: [here](https://github.com/EightMedia/jquery.hammer.js/pull/4) and [here](https://github.com/EightMedia/jquery.hammer.js/issues/3).)

So using the standalone version (which does not include Hammer) seems the safest way to go. You'll have to discard your shim for `jQueryHammer` because as you can see by looking at the code, the plugin will detect an AMD environment (which RequireJS is) and will call `define`. You just need to make sure that the module names `hammer` and `jquery` resolve to the file that contains Hammer and the file that contains jQuery respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Eugene I solved my problem.

Here's my app.js with the correct configuration:

```js
require.config({

    baseUrl: 'js/libs',

    paths: {
        // Directories
        collections: '../collections',
        models: '../models',
        views: '../views',
        templates: '../../templates',

        // Files
        'dualStorage': 'backbone.dualStorage',
        'hammer-jquery': 'jquery.hammer', // jQuery plugin without Hammer
        'jQueryAnimate': 'jquery.animate-enhanced.min'
    },

    shim: {
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'dualStorage': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'backbone']
        }
    }
});

require([
    'jquery',
    'backbone',
    'hammer',
    '../router',
    'hammer-jquery'
], function($, Backbone, Hammer, Router) {
    console.log(Hammer);
    console.log($.fn.hammer);
    var router = new Router();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Install **npm i hammerjs**
2. Add to package.json ===>
   **"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",  "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",  "types": [ "hammerjs",  "jasmine",  "jasminewd2",  "node",  "q",
   "selenium-webdriver" ]**
3. add **import 'hammerjs';** to **main.ts**
   file
4. If you still have problems use:
   **npm --force**
   **npm install**